# How to Pass Parameter values to python Boto3 script using AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm creating a simple webpage which will show aws ec2 instance name and other details. I'm using the Boto3 (which is fetching data into a JSON file) and AJAX GET request to populate that data into the front end. Now I want to POST a Data field to my Boto3 script using AJAX. I have a text field and submit button when a user will be entering its ec2 instance-id and submit the form that field value will pass to the Boto3 script as Instance function parameter value then it will STOP that instance and return some value, I am having a problem while creating the AJAX POST, don't know how to POST value into Boto3. any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

How can i do this using beautifulsoup4.

//my boto3 script for ec2 instance STOP.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2.Instance('i-00434b87058703892').stop() //here i want to use POST value
```

Comment: What Python framework (Flask, etc.) are you using on your server?

Comment: I'm not using any python framework.

Comment: What are you using?

Comment: Python CGI for Html forms